# Are quantum tunneling slow down by time dilation affected?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, observers, time-dilation, quantum-tunneling

If i setup to clock to work at the same rate at stationary. The first clock operated on quantum tunneling. Setup electron to tunneling and repel another electron. Which acts as sensor. The second clock using laser to repel electron. Which acts as sensor. Put both clock in the car that travel near speed of light.  And the observer stay in the car with both clock. What will observer see? The laser clock will working slow down by time dilation. Because the electron, which acts as sensor of the laser clock travel near speed if light. So the laser use longer time to reach the electron to repel it. What about the tunneling clock?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the photon clock equivalent to all clocks?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/570966/)

Comment: If the observer in the car is stationary with respect to both clocks also in the car, then from his perspective the ground outside the car (irrelevant to the clocks) is moving at near light speed and everything in the car is like in the lab. The assertion "the laser clock will working slow down by time dilation" is not true in that case.

Comment: Oh! I see. Thank you.